# How to get preview thumbnails in VideoJS with a VTT file?

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, video.js

I'm trying to use VideoJS as a player and I like to display thumbnails when you use the seekbar as a preview of the video. I have the work done in order to generate vtt files and thumbnails as now I'm using JWPlayer. So I would like to use this VTT file and the thumbs I have generated on JWPlayer. I generate a thumb each 10 seconds and as videos are from 20 to 40 minutes there are a lot of thumbs.

I've found a few VideoJS plugins that do not work with my current config of VTT for JWplayer as they require an sprite and a JSON to load the sprite.

This is my current VTT file:

```
WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:10.000
thumb_0001.jpg

00:00:10.000 --> 00:00:20.000
thumb_0002.jpg

00:00:20.000 --> 00:00:30.000
thumb_0003.jpg

...
```

Is there any way to have and VTT file as described and have preview thumnails on VideoJS without using a sprite?

Comment: VideoJS actually generate video tag for you. If you need your video player create custom subtitles (webVTT) rendering, you must setup your own text track listener or you can follow [this tutorial](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/08/building-interactive-html5-videos/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use various plugins for videojs that can do most of the tasks. To display thumbnails, you can use the following plugin:

https://github.com/dirkjanm/videojs-vtt-thumbnails